# DirectX Device::CreateTexture2D() crashes when calling with all 3 params

Tags: directx

I am gonna try to render a 2D Texture from opencv::Mat to a Texture in DX11 and also to a shaderesource afterwars. The Problem is, the program crashes on **Device::CreateTexture2D()** and I can't figure out why. I researched the whole day, I just don't see whats wrong here.

Furthermore, the Problem seems not to be the cv::Mat as Resource, because I have tried also this example here: [D3D11 CreateTexture2D in 32 bit format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823255/d3d11-createtexture2d-in-32-bit-format) with the chess-example as resource for the texture... and the functions still crashes, when calling with the 3rd param.

I found others, who had Problems with that function, sometimes the Problem was because that SysMemPitch was not set for 2D Textures but that's not the case here unfortunately.

---

Error Output: First-chance exception at 0x692EF11E (igd10iumd32.dll) in ARift.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x03438000.

### Unhandled exception at 0x692EF11E (igd10iumd32.dll) in ARift.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x03438000.

here is the relevant code:

---

```
        bool Texture::InitCameraStream(ID3D11Device* device, ARiftControl* arift_control)
    {
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC td;
    ZeroMemory(&td, sizeof(td));
    td.ArraySize = 1;
    td.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    td.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    td.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    td.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    td.Height = arift_control->picture_1_.size().height;
    td.Width = arift_control->picture_1_.size().width;
    td.MipLevels = 1;
    td.MiscFlags = 0;
    td.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    td.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA srInitData;
    srInitData.pSysMem = arift_control->picture_1_.ptr();
    srInitData.SysMemPitch = arift_control->picture_1_.size().width * 4;

    ID3D11Texture2D* tex = 0;
    if ((device->CreateTexture2D(&td, &srInitData, NULL) == S_FALSE));
    {
          std::cerr << "Texture Description: OK " << std::endl << "Subresource: OK" << std::endl;
    }

    if (FAILED(device->CreateTexture2D(&td, &srInitData, &tex)));
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Texture could not be created! "<< std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    // Create the shader-resource view
    D3D10_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srDesc;
    srDesc.Format = td.Format;
    srDesc.ViewDimension = D3D10_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    srDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
    srDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

    if (FAILED(device->CreateShaderResourceView(tex, NULL, &texture_)));
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't create Shader Resource View" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

CreateTexture2D Returns S_FALSE when the first 2 Parameters are valid, and passing 0 as the 3rd param. So in my case, it also Returns S_FALSE the first time, so the Debug Output appears. When calling CreateTexture2D with the 3rd param (the TExture COM object), it crashed. I have absolutely no idea anymore.

Furthermore, I tried to Setup Debugging with DirectX and followed that tutorial: http://blog.rthand.com/post/2010/10/25/Capture-DirectX-1011-debug-output-to-Visual-Studio.aspx - but I can't see a "Debug" window in my Project Properties in Visual Studio 2013. So I still get to "igd10iumd32.pdb not loaded" window, after the program crashes.

**Edit:** at least I could fix the issue with the additional D3D debug Outputs for now. In my Visual Studio 2013 I had to set the following: Project Properties -> Debugging -> Debug Type -> Mixed for getting the Additional D3D logs :)

Can anyone help here? It's really frustrating, just getting stuck on that single function the whole day ..

Many thanks!

- Max

Comment: igd10iumd32.dll is your graphics driver (Intel). Likely, you're passing some data pointer to it that isn't valid via D3D, and it isn't checking it. I suspect that it's the contents of `D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA`. Does it crash if you omit it (pass NULL as p2)?

Comment: first of all, many thanks for your answer, I am really desperate about that, I am doing the whole day just trying to get that work ... 

device->CreateTexture2D(&tdesc, &srInitData, NULL)  Returns S_FALSE, wich means according to docu that the params are valid and ok.

device->CreateTexture2D(&tdesc, NULL, &tex))) also works, but afterwars it crashed on CreateShaderResourceView

Comment: btw. the used cv::Mat (picture_1_) has a width of 900 and a height of 1600, could that be a Problem somehow? but that would be weird because the first 2 params seems to be valid according to return type of CreateTexture2D (S_FALSE).

Comment: Those dimensions should be fine, but, passing NULL as the second parameter and avoiding the crash has shown that your input data is an issue. Likely your input data is not appropriately sized (ie. it needs to be 900*4 * 1600 bytes).

Comment: Also, to see the debug output from the debug D3D runtime, the "output window" they are talking about is the debug output from the process. From VS menus, it's View->Output (or Alt+2), and set the dropdown to "Debug". Usually this pops up by default when you start debugging.

Comment: oh? how can I Change that? currently I am just loading this Image into a cv::Mat: http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/p__/images/d/d8/Wall-E_Planet2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140428175218&path-prefix=protagonist How do I Need to Change that for Fitting D3D exactly? This Picture is just a testpicture for now, later on I am gonna render the camera stream to a 2D Texture

Comment: I am sorry for confusing. I was talking from a different "Debug" property. There seems to be a way to get additional DirectX Debug ouput. I was following this to achieve it: http://blog.rthand.com/post/2010/10/25/Capture-DirectX-1011-debug-output-to-Visual-Studio.aspx but I got stuck on step [3] because there is no "Debug" section in Project properties

Comment: In that post, the project settings suggest they are using C#. If you have a native C++ app (you are using C++ code after all), you don't need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input texture data passed in `D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA` is not sufficiently sized. In your comment, you said that the input image data is 900x1600, and the link is a JPEG. However, you are specifying to D3D that the data format is `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM`. JPEG is a compressed format, thus, the data stream will be smaller than it would be in BGRA format. When your drive (igd10iumd32.dll) attempts to read this input stream, it crashes because the buffer is not as large as you told D3D it was.

You can use `D3DX11CreateTextureFromFile` to load JPEG data. There are also some free image conversion libraries you can use to convert the JPEG into a D3D natively compatible format.

Comment: oh okay. Anyway, this was just a test Picture. As I mentioned, I actually want to render the camera stream as Texture. Camera Mode is currently set to **RGB8**, which means **8 Bits / Channel, 24 Bits / Pixel and 24 Bits in Total**. With that Format there is no Alpha channel. So I Need to use **DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM** for my Texture, am I right with that? That's all? The **SystemPith stays "width * 4"** so? Many thanks for your help, I appreciate that! :)

Comment: no problem, but, that is a different question. Mark this as answered, and ask another if something else doesn't work...

Comment: ok I set as answered. Thanks again. I am gonna make a new question now :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have still Problems with **CreateShaderResourceView()**. Can't figure out.  I have set up 2 other questions here on StackOverflow to hopefully solve that. If you have time, I would be very glad if you could help me one more time. **[1]** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265034/directx11-render-camerastream-to-texture-devicecreateshaderresourceview-fail , **[2]** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316524/directx11-cant-set-texture2d-as-shaderresourceview - many thanks!