# directx11 - can't set Texture2D as ShaderResourceView?

Tags: directx, textures

I have written a little DirectX RenderEngine, to render and texture simple Polygons. The texturing worked with CreateDDSTextureFromFile(.dds) very well.

Now, I try to set up a Texture and a corresponding ShaderResourceView from a Memory buffer. Creating the Texture2D works, but then, **CreateShaderResourceView ALWAYS fails**. Also tried to call it with 2nd param set to NULL, also fails. I was trying to figure out what's wrong here for the whole week.

I hope somebody can help me here.

**[Code]**:

```
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC tdesc;
ZeroMemory(&tdesc, sizeof(tdesc));
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA srInitData;
ZeroMemory(&srInitData, sizeof(srInitData));
ID3D11Texture2D* tex = 0;
D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srDesc;
ZeroMemory(&srDesc, sizeof(srDesc));

// ------------------------- [CHECK MATE ] ----------------------------
int w = 512;
int h = 512;
int bpp = 4;
int *buf = new int[w*h];

// filling the image
for (int i = 0; i<h; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j<w; j++)
    {
        if ((i & 32) == (j & 32))
            buf[i*w + j] = 0x00000000;
        else
            buf[i*w + j] = 0xffffffff;
    }

// setting up D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA 
srInitData.pSysMem = (void *)buf;
srInitData.SysMemPitch = w*bpp;
srInitData.SysMemSlicePitch = w*h*bpp; // Not needed since this is a 2d texture

// setting up D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC 
tdesc.Width = w;
tdesc.Height = h;
tdesc.MipLevels = 1;
tdesc.ArraySize = 1;
tdesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
tdesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
tdesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
tdesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
tdesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
tdesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
tdesc.MiscFlags = 0;

// checking inputs
if (device->CreateTexture2D(&tdesc, &srInitData, NULL) == S_FALSE)
    std::cout << "Inputs correct" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "wrong inputs" << std::endl;

// create the texture
if (FAILED(device->CreateTexture2D(&tdesc, &srInitData, &tex)))
{
    std::cout << "Failed" << std::endl;
    return(0);
}
else
    std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;


// setup the Shader Resource Desc.
srDesc.Format = tdesc.Format;
srDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
srDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
srDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

// ------------------ [ Here it always Fails ...]
if (FAILED(device->CreateShaderResourceView(tex, &srDesc, &texture_)));
{
    std::cerr << "Can't create Shader Resource View" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

delete[] buf;
```

**[Sidequestion]**: I noticed when I Change the **D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC.USAGE to D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC**, CreateTexture2D aswell fails. but why?

**[Debug]**: ...
 D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Buffer: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x00C31374, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097228: CREATE_BUFFER]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Buffer: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x00C319A4, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097228: CREATE_BUFFER]
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x9c8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11Texture2D: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x00C41984, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097234: CREATE_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 INFO: Create ID3D11ShaderResourceView: Name="unnamed", Addr=0x00C41F6C, ExtRef=1, IntRef=0 [ STATE_CREATION INFO #2097240: CREATE_SHADERRESOURCEVIEW]

.. doesn't say much to me, can't see anything of an error hint here.

**[Note]**: actually I want to use a RGBA8 Texture from Camera Input (stored in a buffer) - but I could not achieve that. So I tried this example, to find out why **CreateShaderResourceView** fails even with a normal int* buffer.

I am very thankful for any help! thanks!

**[Solved]** as the code above, I always reached the output "Can't create Shader Resource View" assuming CreateShaderResourceView failed. Checking HRESULT, it's value was S_OK, which seemed strange to me. So I just changed the condition for a try:

```
if (SUCCEEDED(device->CreateShaderResourceView(tex, &srDesc, &texture_)));
{
    std::cout << "Successfully created ShaderResourceView" << std::endl;
    delete[] buf;
    return true;
}
return false;
```

And it worked. This behavior seems really odd to me, but I am finally glad it works. So Also the camera stream works now, many thanks to Adam Miles for the support! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG on device creation flags to get exact error messages printed out when a function fails.

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot to mention above. I already enabled the flag, but it does not say anything useful to me, so I did not mention it. Added the post above! :)

Comment: What is the error code returned by CreateShaderResourceView? You just print something if it fails, but the error code might tell you a lot about what's wrong.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer! The HRESULT of  CreateShaderResourceView  is simply 0.

Comment: 0 is S_OK, suggesting that the function hasn't failed. Does it crash inside CreateShaderResourceView or actually return and print "Can't create Shader Resource View"?

Comment: how shall I check that to be sure? I mean the if(FAILED(..) is true after calling the function. I have done exactly same if(FAIL(condition)) previously by using **CreateWICTextureFromMemory** with a .jpg and it did not print and worked. btw. is there a Chat possibility here or something?

Comment: The return code can't be 0 if FAIL(result) returns true. 0 is the only non-fail error code. Put a breakpoint on your "std::cerr << "Can't create Shader Resource View" << std::endl;" and see if it hits it. If it does, then the HRESULT from CreateShaderResourceView can't have been 0 as you said. I don't know what a "Chat possibility" is...

Comment: I can't believe it, it worked! how did that happen, somehow I made a really bad mistake with checking for if(FAILED()) on the CreateShaderResource function. HRESULT was S_OK, so i checked afterwars if(result != S_OK) {error} - but it was S_OK here. So i changed the condition, if(result == S_OK) {success] - and it successed! I am not sure if I am just very confused currently, or the condiion if(result != S_OK) is a bad idea here.

Comment: I am so glad it works now, even if the behavior seems very odd to me here. Many thanks for your input!! ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is years late, but the problem seems to be that the code in the question will be parsed like this:

```
if (FAILED(device->CreateShaderResourceView(tex, &srDesc, &texture_)))
     ;

// unconditionally executed:
{
    std::cerr << "Can't create Shader Resource View" << std::endl;
    return false;
}
```

due to the semicolon at the end of the `if` line.