# Creating or Updating DirectX11 texture gives Access Violation Exception

Tags: c++, directx-11, texture2d

I am trying to make a simple test to understand DirectX11 better and how to work with `ID3D11Texture2D`.

I am willing to create an `ID3D11Texture2D` from `unsigned char[]`, but for some reason it is giving me the following error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBBCB9C21E (nvwgf2umx.dll) in TestDX.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000024B1A7A4000.
```

I have created the `D3D11CreateDevice` with debug flags and it does not show any more useful information.

After looking up in the internet, [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217421/directx-devicecreatetexture2d-crashes-when-calling-with-all-3-params#comment46668674_29217421) suggests that my `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC`
`Format` property does not match the input data format.

To reproduce, here is my code:

```
const int width = 1920;
const int height = 1080;

unsigned char* pixels = new unsigned char[width * height * 4];

int numPixels = (int)(width * height);

// Setting up pixels
for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) 
{
    *(pixels) = 255;
    *(pixels + 1) = 255;
    *(pixels + 2) = 255;
    *(pixels + 3) = 255;
    pixels += 4; // move the pointer along to the next rgba pixel
}

// Creating DirectX11 Device
UINT creationFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
};

ID3D11Texture2D* tex = nullptr;
ID3D11Device* device = nullptr;
ID3D11DeviceContext* context = nullptr; 

if (FAILED(D3D11CreateDevice(
    nullptr,                    // specify nullptr to use the default adapter
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    nullptr,                    // specify nullptr because D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE 
                                // indicates that this function uses hardware
    creationFlags,              // optionally set debug and Direct2D compatibility flags
    featureLevels,
    ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,          // always set this to D3D11_SDK_VERSION
    &device,
    nullptr,
    &context)))
{
    cout << "Failed creating device" << endl;
    return 0;
}
else
{
    cout << "Created device" << endl;
}

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData = { 0 };
initData.pSysMem = (const void*)pixels;
initData.SysMemPitch = width * 4 * sizeof(unsigned char);
initData.SysMemSlicePitch = height * width * 4;

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC tex_desc = {};
tex_desc.Height = height;
tex_desc.Width = width;
tex_desc.MipLevels = 1;
tex_desc.ArraySize = 1;
tex_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
tex_desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
tex_desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
tex_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
tex_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;
tex_desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
tex_desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GENERATE_MIPS;

HRESULT hres = device->CreateTexture2D(&tex_desc, &initData, &tex); // Causes exception

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Could not create texture" << endl;
    return 0;
}
else
{
    cout << "Created texture" << endl;
}

if (tex)
{
    tex->Release();
}
```

I also tried creating an empty texture and using UpdateSubresource as someone suggested in the internet and created this scenario:

```
const int width = 1920;
const int height = 1080;

unsigned char* pixels = new unsigned char[width * height * 4];

int numPixels = (int)(width * height);

// Setting up pixels
for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++)
{
    *(pixels) = 255;
    *(pixels + 1) = 255;
    *(pixels + 2) = 255;
    *(pixels + 3) = 255;
    pixels += 4; // move the pointer along to the next rgba pixel
}

// Creating DirectX11 Device
UINT creationFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
};

ID3D11Texture2D* tex = nullptr;
ID3D11Device* device = nullptr;
ID3D11DeviceContext* context = nullptr;

if (FAILED(D3D11CreateDevice(
    nullptr,                    // specify nullptr to use the default adapter
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    nullptr,                    // specify nullptr because D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE 
                                // indicates that this function uses hardware
    creationFlags,              // optionally set debug and Direct2D compatibility flags
    featureLevels,
    ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,          // always set this to D3D11_SDK_VERSION
    &device,
    nullptr,
    &context)))
{
    cout << "Failed creating device" << endl;
    return 0;
}
else
{
    cout << "Created device" << endl;
}

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC tex_desc = {};
tex_desc.Height = height;
tex_desc.Width = width;
tex_desc.MipLevels = 1;
tex_desc.ArraySize = 1;
tex_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
tex_desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
tex_desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
tex_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
tex_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;
tex_desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
tex_desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GENERATE_MIPS;

HRESULT hres = device->CreateTexture2D(&tex_desc, NULL, &tex);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Could not create texture" << endl;
    return 0;
}
else
{
    cout << "Created texture" << endl;
}

int row_pitch = (width * 4) * sizeof(unsigned char);

context->UpdateSubresource(tex, 0, NULL, pixels, row_pitch, 0); // Causes exception

if (tex)
{
    tex->Release();
}
```

However, both scenarios lead to the same exception and I think it suggests that my input data is actually wrong, but I don't see why it is wrong. My `pixels` do represent an RGBA image and I set the `tex_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` which looks correct to me but I am not experienced at all with this so I can't really judge.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with DirectX, your code modifies the original `pixels` pointer (`pixels++`, etc.) so it passes garbage (and eventually pointer to locked/unallocated OS memory pages because it's a big-sized buffer) as initial data, hence the crash.

So, for example, change this:

```
unsigned char* pixels = new unsigned char[width * height * 4];
```

to this:

```
unsigned char* pixels = new unsigned char[width * height * 4];
unsigned char* mem = pixels;
```

and change this:

```
initData.pSysMem = (const void*)pixels;
```

to this:

```
initData.pSysMem = (const void*)mem;
```